# compiling with gcc with system()

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

My code does not compile right when I use:

`system("gcc -o filename temp.c");`

I am getting:

`implicit declaration of function system`

I'm not sure what is missing, because it only throws the system error on the gcc call.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        ...
        system("gcc -o filename temp.c");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add `#include <stdlib.h>` after `#include <stdio.h>` - that is where the prototype for `system` is - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top of `main()`.

*Tip*: When you see implicit declaration of a built-in function, you have to search for the function (with google, for example now you should have searched with "system() C"), in order to find the corresponding header, i.e. where the function is declared. Then one of the results should be the ref of the function.

In our case [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html) link. There you can see:

> SYNOPSIS

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int system(const char *command);
```

which tells you that you have to include `stdlib` header to use `system()`.

As Mr. Bright noticed, if you're on on a inux-like OS, `man 3 system` should do the trick too.

Example:

```
samaras@samaras-A15:~$ man 3 system
SYSTEM(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 SYSTEM(3)

NAME
       system - execute a shell command

SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdlib.h>  <-- this is what we are looking for!

       int system(const char *command);
...
```

Comment: If you're on on a unixy OS, `man 3 system` should do the trick too.

Comment: Ok, so if something throws a implicit declaration of function, it means that there is header file missing?

Comment: Yes @JoshBuchanan, not any header though, the header that needs to be included by that particular function at the time. Now `system()` required `stdlib.h` to be included. Nice question though, you got my +1. Hope you keep my tip, it will help I believe!

Comment: @G.Samaras Thank you, I will keep that in mind, this is like my third C program. Still trying to figure out what to look and when.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears you are using a Posix system, you should know about the `man` command which shows documentation for most library calls. On my system, when I type:

```
$ man system
```

I get:

```
SYSTEM(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 

NAME
       system - execute a shell command

SYNOPSIS
       #include <stdlib.h>

       int system(const char *command);
```

Notice that in the synopsis it tells you the include file you need to use. The man page also includes a lot of other documentation such as the return value.

Answer (score -2):

You are not getting an error, and is not preventing the compilation of the code, it's just a warning that you have not added the library system function, but gcc adds automatically.